# Standard deviation of a baised $d$-sided coin

Tags: probability, information-theory, standard-deviation

I know that that standard deviation of a noisy bit (a biased coin with probability distribution $\{ p, 1-p \}$ ) is given by 
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)} $$

What is then a measure of the standard deviation for the d-dimensional variant? e.g. for $d=3$ we have state space $$\{p_1, p_2, 1-p_1-p_2\}$$

Many thanks!

Comment: I assume the outcomes are $0, 1, 2, \ldots, d-1$?

Comment: Are the outcomes $\{0,1,2,\ldots,d-1\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\ldots,d\}$??

Comment: @cjferes, since the question is about the standard deviation, a shift in the variable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer in development**

Let a $d$-sided coin have sides labeled $X\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,d\}$, and let the state space be
$$\{p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_d\}$$
this is, $p_i$ is the probability of throwing the side labeled $i$. Note that $$\sum_{i=1}^dp_i=1$$

Then, the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, and:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{Var}(X)&=&\displaystyle \mathrm{E}\{X^2\}-\mathrm{E}^2\{X\}\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i (p_ix_i^2)-\mu^2\\
\end{array}$$

Where
$$\mu=\mathrm{E}\{X\}=\sum p_ix_i=p_1+2p_2+\ldots+dp_d$$

Therefore
$$\mu^2=\mathrm{E}^2\{X\}=\bigl(\sum_i p_ix_i\bigr)^2=\sum_i\sum_j p_ix_ip_jx_j=(p_1+2p_2+\ldots+dp_d)^2$$

And
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{Var}(X)&=&\displaystyle \sum_i (p_ix_i^2)-\mu^2\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i \bigl(p_ix_i^2\bigr)-\sum_i\sum_jp_ix_ip_jx_j\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i \bigl(p_ix_i^2\bigr)-\biggl(\sum_i\sum_j p_ix_ip_jx_j\biggr)\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i \bigl(p_ix_i^2\bigr)-\biggl(\sum_i p_i^2x_i^2+\sum_i\sum_{j,j\neq i} p_ix_ip_jx_j\biggr)\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i \bigl(p_ix_i^2\bigr)-\sum_i p_i^2x_i^2-\sum_i\sum_{j,j\neq i} p_ix_ip_jx_j\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i \bigl(p_ix_i^2-p_i^2x_i^2\bigr)-\sum_i\sum_{j,\,j\neq i} p_ix_ip_jx_j\\
&=&\displaystyle \sum_i p_i(1-p_i)x_i^2-\sum_i\sum_{j,\,j\neq i} p_ix_ip_jx_j\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: This is not right.  You should get the same answer even if you assign $1$ for heads and $2$ for tails but your formula gives a different answer.  The error is where you say $\sum (p_i x_i^2) - \mu^2 = \sum ((p_i x_i^2) - (p_i x_i)^2)$.

Comment: ouch, editing now

Comment: my answer is in development, but may be useful to find the final answer

Comment: thank you for your help! This is where I have the same problem - every time I derive a final function for the variance it isnt symmetric under relabelling/renumberating of states

Comment: Looks correct, but I wonder the first formula (which is basically the definition of the variance for an arbitrary discrete variable) is not preferable to the last one. BTW, isn't $x_i=i$ here?

Comment: I'm still wrapping up the details, because I'm trying to get to a final expression for the variance in this case. Also, $x_i=i$ indeed, but I haven't found a way yet to use that fact (also, teh variance shouldn't depend on a shift of the values...)